# Authenticate to Kusto using managed identities in Python

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-data-explorer

I'm trying to improve authentication to my Kusto clusters from my functions once they're deployed into production environment. Locally, I connect thru AZ CLI authentication, but I've found out that my organization generated a user assigned managed identity for my Kusto cluster.

I have a `principalId` and a `clientId`. How do I authenticate using the managed identity?

TIA

Answer (score 1):

See example for use of MI Auth in the below link.
Please mind MIs only work when running in Azure in a host that this MI was attached to.

https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-python/blob/80cd8b61b681069e461141c98f4d7e29cdb4a783/azure-kusto-data/tests/sample.py#L61

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Does it mean I cannot use MI's locally when authenticating?

Comment: Yes. MI's are available on Azure only

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you got not a manged identity but a application identity. This is a service account in azure ad.

That way, you can get a oauth2 token and use it to query the service.